# Angular Jasmine Unit Test NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[CheckForUpdateService -> CheckForUpdateService]:

Tags: angular, jasmine

First the service I want to test

```
@Injectable()
export class CheckForUpdateService {

  constructor(appRef: ApplicationRef, updates: SwUpdate) {
    console.log('CheckForUpdateService started');

    // Allow the app to stabilize first, before starting polling for updates with `interval()`.
    const appIsStable$ = appRef.isStable.pipe(first(isStable => isStable === true));
    const everySixHours$ = interval(6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
    const everySixHoursOnceAppIsStable$ = concat(appIsStable$, everySixHours$);

    everySixHoursOnceAppIsStable$.subscribe(() => {
      updates.checkForUpdate()
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Service Workers disabled or not supported in this browser');
        });
    });

  }
}
```

and here my unit test

```
describe('CheckForUpdateService', () => {
  let service: CheckForUpdateService;
  // Parameters for constructor
  let applicationRefSpy: ApplicationRef;
  let swUpdateSpy: SwUpdate;

  beforeEach(() => {
    applicationRefSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('ApplicationRef', [''], {
      ['isStable']: of(true)
    });
    swUpdateSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SwUpdate',
      {
        ['checkForUpdate']: Promise.resolve()
      });


    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        { provide: ApplicationRef, useValue: applicationRefSpy },
        { provide: SwUpdate, useValue: swUpdateSpy }

      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(CheckForUpdateService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I am getting the error:

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(CompilerModule)[CheckForUpdateService -> CheckForUpdateService]:
  NullInjectorError: No provider for CheckForUpdateService!
error properties: Object({ ngTempTokenPath: null, ngTokenPath: [ 'CheckForUpdateService', 'CheckForUpdateService' ] })
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?
Am I understanding correctly, that the unit test can't find any providers for the check-for-update.service?

Answer (score 4):

Adding

```
CheckForUpdateService
```

into the providers for the TestingModule configuration solved this issue for me.

I think this is because my service is not injected anywhere.

```
@Injectable()
```

Answer (score 4):

The service needs to be registered in the module.  You can configure itself to be automatically registered in the root module by changing your injectable attribute to this.

> @Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error appeared because I fetched the service in question from the `TestBed` in the wrong way. I had erroneously written:

```
checkForUpdateServiceSpy = TestBed.get('CheckForUpdateService')
```

instead of

```
checkForUpdateServiceSpy = TestBed.get(CheckForUpdateService)
```